# Pickpocketing through powers in GURPS

Tags: character-creation, skills, powers, gurps-4e

One of my players was thinking of creating "the best pickpocket evar" in GURPS 4e. Naturally, there will be some skills involved, but he's envisioning crazy stuff, like he's standing 5 feet away and the item is literally locked to the mark's body (or ingested). It's Illuminati University with an anime bent, so anything goes. However, it is also low mana, so magic spells alone won't be that reliable. The characters are at 170 points right now (45 point disad/quirk limit), so he'd be building off that.

I'm thinking either modifying the Snatcher ability or the Warp ability. The Snatcher seems more "correct", but it doesn't really fit because it's getting a specific item from a person, not a generic "I need an item". Warp would work, but you'd need the "Blind" enhancement and it's very limited to a certain set of conditions (get one item from a person). And I would like it tied to a Pickpocket skill, not just a "it's done".

The player is making the case that it's about 50 points.

So, two questions:

1. How would you build this power and how many points would it cost?
2. Any potential game issues I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cross-posted to here:

http://forums.sjgames.com/showthread.php?t=97336

Two options:

1. Affliction (Warp) (1) (Based on Pickpocket; Accessibility (Cannot be performed on held item) (+2); Advantage (Warp, Exoteleport only) (+50); Malediction (Receives -1/yd range); No Signature; Psionic; Reduced Range (x1/2); Resistible (Per) (Per)) [65]
2. Affliction 1 (Per vs Pickpocket; Based on Per for target, +20%; Based on Per for you, +20%; Warp*, +200%) [34]

   *Warp (Accessibility, Only if unobserved, -20%; Accessibility, Only places you could walk/climb to, given time, -20%; Exoteleport, -50%; No Strain, +25%; Range Limit, -50%) [20]